# Python: Get the line and column number of string index?

Tags: python, file, text

Say I have a text file I'm operating on. Something like this (hopefully this isn't too unreadable):

```
data_raw = open('my_data_file.dat').read()
matches = re.findall(my_regex, data_raw, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    try:
        parse(data_raw, from_=match.start(), to=match.end())
    except Exception:
        print("Error parsing data starting on line {}".format(what_do_i_put_here))
        raise
```

Notice in the exception handler there's a certain variable named `what_do_i_put_here`. My question is: how can I assign to that name so that my script will print the **line number** that contains the start of the 'bad region' I'm trying to work with? I don't mind re-reading the file, I just don't know what I'd do...

Comment: Does your regular expression consume new lines? If it doesn't, you can just findall line by line, and then it's easy to get the line number.

Comment: Yes, it consumes multiple lines (which is why I used `re.MULTILINE`)

Comment: Doesn't re.findall return a list of strings?: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. Strings do not have start, or end methods.

Comment: No, it returns a list `MatchObject` instances, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject

Answer (score 3):

Here's something a bit cleaner, and in my opinion easier to understand than your own answer:

```
def index_to_coordinates(s, index):
    """Returns (line_number, col) of `index` in `s`."""
    if not len(s):
        return 1, 1
    sp = s[:index+1].splitlines(keepends=True)
    return len(sp), len(sp[-1])
```

It works essentially the same way as your own answer, but by utilizing string slicing `splitlines()` actually calculates all the information you need for you without the need for any post processing.

Using the `keepends=True` is necessary to give correct column counts for end of line characters.

The only extra problem is the edge case of an empty string, which can easily be handled by a guard-clause.

I tested it in Python 3.8, but it probably works correctly after about version 3.4 (in some older versions `len()` counts code units instead of code points, and I assume it would break for any string containing characters outside of the BMP)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this. It's untested and inefficient but it does help my exception message be a little clearer:

```
def coords_of_str_index(string, index):
    """Get (line_number, col) of `index` in `string`."""
    lines = string.splitlines(True)
    curr_pos = 0
    for linenum, line in enumerate(lines):
        if curr_pos + len(line) > index:
            return linenum + 1, index-curr_pos
        curr_pos += len(line)
```

I haven't even tested to see if the column number is vaguely accurate. I failed to abide by YAGNI

Comment: I'd suggest to use `s` to avoid shadowing the standard library `string` module.

Answer (score 0):

Column indexing starts with 0 so you need to extract 1 from len(sp[-1]) at the very end of your code to get the correct column value. Also, I'd perhaps return None (instead of "1.1" - which is also incorrect since it should be "1.0"...) if the lenght of string is 0 or if the string is too short to fit the index.
Otherwise, **it's an excellent and elegant solution** Tim.

```
def index_to_coordinates(txt:str, index:int) -> str:
    """Returns 'line.column' of index in 'txt'."""
    if not txt or len(txt)-1 < index:
        return None
    sp = txt[:index+1].splitlines(keepends=True)
    return (f"{len(sp)}.{len(sp[-1])-1}")
```